# Linux Paging and interrupt handler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, paging

Dear Sir/Madam,
I am trying to implement ready boost feature in LINUX for my final year undergraduate project.I was just researching and I found out that whenever a page fault occurs the CPU sends Interrupt 14.So, I need your guidance on the foll scheme I am thinking of:
I will create an interrupt handler which will be activated when an interrupt occurs.
This handler can extract the linear address of the fault from cr2 register and we can use LINUX page table to get the physical address.
Do you think that this ,will be a feasible scheme?
Also any tutorial on the same will be highly appreciated.
Thanks to all in advance.
_Regards

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "ReadyBoost" simply implemented by running `mkswap` followed by `swapon` on the `/dev/sd*` device special file for the flash disk?  As far as I'm aware, all the necessary kernel-side support is in place.

Comment: Well sir,
I tried it but the error is that Access is denied....
But are you sure that this can be done??
Also,I would like to know about the feasibility of the scheme stated above....
-Thanks for the reply anyway..

Answer (score 0):

We're not going to do your assignment for you.

IIUI ReadyBoost is not the same as swap @caf. It is about caching disk content on a faster medium to make random disk accesses faster. Linux will never page disk-backed pages to swap, they will just be dropped and reread from the disk. Only anonymous pages go to swap.

Also ReadyBoost data is mirrored to disk, so the USB drive can be removed at any time, and also encrypted so if the key is removed and analysed on another system nothing is disclosed.

So @R-The_Master you could implement something like ReadyBoost for Linux. But it has basically nothing to do with `int 14`.

Comment: Respected Sir, Appreaciate ur comments but this wasn't my assigment ...this is a part of it...so don't worry abt me tellin you to do my assignment..

Comment: Also,as I asked  in the original question..I can create my own module and implement paging with the logic of readyboost...and this module will be activated when int 14 is thrown by the hardware..

Comment: pls giimme ur feedback on this sir..also...any resource will be appreciated